# Two way SSL/TLS

Tags: php, ubuntu

It is my first experience with two way ssl/tls authentication and I need to understand how to setup this solution.
I have a partner that send me a CA certificate, and I generate my own certificate.

so how I can configure all that ?

1 - I must install the partner CA certificate in my ubuntu server ( how to do that ?)

2 - I must sent my crt certificat the the partener ( he will install it in his own server )

3 - Each request I must provide my certificat private key

Is it the correct my to setup the solution ?

No web server used I have juste a PHP code that call the web service via SoapClient

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, [
    'local_cert' => 'PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY',
    'trace' => true
]);
```

Thank you

I already try this steps but I have the error ssl handshake failed

Answer (score 0):

You can add cert to trusted or you can turn off ssl verification to solve your problem. The second way is very easier.

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
]);

$client  = new SoapClient($wsdl, [
    'stream_context' => $context
]);
```